# Proof of cross product in orthogonal transformation (using levi civita)

Tags: vector-spaces, tensors, classical-mechanics, cross-product

I am trying the following proof. If objects X and Y transform as vectors under orthogonal transformation, then the cross product of X and Y also transforms as vector.  So I try this way;

Let

$$x_{j}^{'} = a_{jn}x_{n}$$ and $$y_{k}^{'} = a_{km}y_{m}$$

Assume: $$\vec{z} = \vec{x} \times \vec{y}$$
I would like to show the `i`th component of the z is as follow (hence complete the proof);
ie. $$z_{i}^{'} = (\vec{x}\times \vec{y})_{i} = a_{ij} z_{j}$$

I started like below (I understand here):
$$z_{i}^{'} = \varepsilon_{ijk} x_{j}^{'}y_{k}^{'} = \varepsilon_{ijk}a_{jn}x_{n}a_{km}y_{m} $$

Then according to a book, it says;
$$ = \varepsilon_{ijk}a_{jn}x_{n}a_{km}y_{m}  = \varepsilon_{nml}a_{il}x_{n}y_{m} = a_{ij}\varepsilon_{jnm}x_{n}y_{m} = a_{ij}z_{j}$$

I am bit confused how these levi civita tensor is changing to **nml**, $$\varepsilon_{nml}$$ and the next step.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I think you are assuming $A$ is special orthogonal, not just orthogonal.  This is just $\varepsilon_{ijk}a_{jn}a_{km}=\varepsilon_{nml}a_{il}$ which follows from $\varepsilon$ being a pseudotensor and inverting one of the $Q$'s in the transformation rule $\varepsilon_{ijk}=\Delta Q_{im}Q_{jn}Q_{kl}\varepsilon_{mnl}$ (i.e., contracting with $Q^{-1}$) with $Q=A^{-1}=A^T$, and finally relabelling the suffices to match.

Comment: thank you. that helps!